# Which action is broadcasted on removing Ethernet connection through otg in android

Tags: android

When ETHERNET is connected via OTG to android phone, i was able to get Broadcast event `ConnectivityManager.INET_CONDITION_ACTION` and when disconnected from ETHERNET not able to get any event.

I tried `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`, but i was not getting this broadcast.

Can anyone help me how to detect event, when Ethernet is disconnected from mobile. I was not able to find this broadcast, so that ethernet icon was not getting removed.

If i get this event, i can remove this ethernet symbol from UI.

Comment: Couldn't make it work with broadcasts... A workaround in my case was to check a system property. A drawback of the approach is to check the property periodically. If you'd like I could share the solution.

Comment: Thank you, pl share

Comment: Not sure about Ethernet cable connected via OTG, but with having it connected directly into Ethernet port of a device I periodically looked at the following value: `cat /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier`, where `1` - connected and `0` - disconnected. Use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to `cat` the value from the code... Let me know if it works and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Its better to send our own broadcast, from where Ethernet service is being disconnected.

Comment: _"Its better to send our own broadcast, from where Ethernet service is being disconnected."_ Then modify AOSP.

Comment: Please modify AOSP with your solution, So that we can have it in android O.

Comment: @G murali Madhav How much are you going to pay me for such a WAY TOO NONTRIVIAL task???